# Google+ sign in not working correctly

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-play-games

I've been following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) for logging in with google+ and google play games from the android developer pages. However, when my app starts, I need to press the google+ button twice before I'm fully logged in. The first time I press it it asks which account I want to use (there are two google accounts on my device) and the second time I press it it shows me the "welcome" pop-up in the top of my screen (with the google play player level). Also, when I press the logout button, the app shows the login button again, but when I press the login button it won't log in again.

**TL;DR**: Have to press the login button twice to login and after logging out the login button won't work at all anymore.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public SharedPreferences prefs;

    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;
    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

    boolean mExplicitSignOut =true; // set to true since we don't want an automatic login untill the user has done a manual login
    boolean mInSignInFlow = false; // set to true when you're in the middle of the
    // sign in flow, to know you should not attempt
    // to connect in onStart()

    // Every "clickable" item in this application (buttons, etc)
    final static int[] CLICKABLES = {
       R.id.sign_in_button,
       R.id.sign_out_button
    };

    private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // set the onClickListener to every "clickable" view
        for (int id: CLICKABLES) {
            findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                        // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Connected; change GUI accordingly

        // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            // Already resolving
            return;
        }

        // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
        // launch the sign-in flow
        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
            // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
            // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
            // an issue with sign in, please try again later."
            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                    mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            }
        }
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mInSignInFlow && !mExplicitSignOut) {
            // auto sign in
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            mExplicitSignOut = false;
            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            // sign out.
            mSignInClicked = false;
            // user explicitly signed out, so turn off auto sign in
            mExplicitSignOut = true;
            if (isSignedIn()) {
                Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }

            // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- sign-in button -->
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- sign-out button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can see this please http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: I've already seen a lot of examples, including those from google. However, I can't seem to be able to figure out in what ways my login / logout code is different from the examples I've seen. Also, using `Log.d`, I could figure out that the connect and disconnect functions are reached at the appropriate moments.

Comment: I've downloaded the source in the link and compiled it, but after clicking the log in button nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to implement `onActivityResult` to catch the result of `BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure`.  You will want something like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
            if (request == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
                if (response == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                } else {
                    BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this, request, response, R.string.signin_other_error);
                }
            }
        }
```

You can see that when `RESULT_OK` is returned we are calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`, which has the same effect as your manual second click that you described.